# How do you show a loading indicator when you click on a button that calls an asynchronous function? React.JS / Amplify Auth

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, aws-amplify

I have login component with controlled inputs, button component (which switch between button and loader based on props) and an async function that calls the login onClick. I put the loading state in login component and pass isLoading state to button component as prop.
The problem is that the API call function is async so i can't use setIsLoading(true) followed by API call and then setIsLoading(false) but i need to show (immediately) that something is going to happen :)

Well, I expect loader to show immediately when onClick is fired, but it shows with delay. I think after Preflight Request of signIn or since handleFetchData is async react first call await function and then setState.

**LoginForm.js**

```
import { useState } from "react";
import "./Blog.css";
import Button from "../../UI/Button/Button";
import { signIn } from "aws-amplify/auth";

const LoginForm = props => {
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);

    const handleFetchData = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        setIsLoading(true);
        const result = await signIn({username: "user@example.com", password: "passWor1"});
        setIsLoading(false);
        console.log(result);
    }

    return (
        <div className="container">
            <Button text="Submit" isLoading={isLoading} action={(e) => handleFetchData(e)}/>
        </div>
    )
}

export default LoginForm;
```

**Button.js**

```
import Loader from "../Loader/Loader";
import styles from "./Button.module.css";

const Button = ({action, color="blue", text="Submit", isLoading=false}) => {

    return (
        <>
            {isLoading? <Loader withImage={false} margin="22px auto 12px auto" /> :
            <button className={[styles.button, styles[color]].join(" ")} type="button"
            onClick={(e) =>{
                e.target.blur();
                action(e)
            }} >{text}</button>}
        </>
    )
}

export default Button;
```

Comment: inside handleFetchData 

e.preventDefault();
        setIsLoading(() => {
signIn({username: "user@example.com", password: "passWor1"})
.then((res) => { // do something with sign in result })
.then(() => setIsLoading(false));

return true;
);

not a good pattern to use in general, But I think will do your work.

Answer (score 1):

Typically this is done with an async state library like [Tanstack-Query](https://tanstack.com/query/latest/docs/framework/react/overview)  or [RTK-Query](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/overview) (if you're using redux).

e.g. (using Tanstack-Query)

```
import { useQuery } from "react-query"
import "./Blog.css";
import Button from "../../UI/Button/Button";
import { signIn } from "aws-amplify/auth";

const loginQueryFn = ({ queryKey }) => signIn({username: "user@example.com", password: "passWor1"});
const loginQueryKey = ["login"];

const LoginForm = props => {
    const [enabled, setEnabled] = useState(false);

    const handleOnClick = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        setEnabled(true);
    }
    const { isLoading, data: result } = useQuery({
        queryKey: loginQueryKey,
        queryFn: loginQueryFn,
        enabled: !!enabled
    });

    return (
        <div className="container">
            <Button 
               text="Submit" 
               isLoading={isLoading}
               action={handleOnClick}
            />
        </div>
    )
}

export default LoginForm;
```